# What is the easiest way to generate a Java client from an RPC encoded WSDL

Tags: java, web-services

I’m new to the concept of web services and I’m currently working on a project where I need to retrieve some data from an external application via SOAP.

This application provides an RPC encoded WSDL. I’m currently finding it very difficult to create a client for this service in Java due to RPC being superseded.

The closest I’ve got so far is using JAX-RPC but every time I try to run the ws-compile programme I get an error which states “error code to large”.

I have researched on AXIS 2, and tried to compile it’s WSDL2JAVA but due to RPC encoding I keep getting exception on all the data binding methods.

I was wondering if I can have some advice or a guide on generating Java Clients from RPC encoded WSDLs. What are the steps? What should I consider before I even try to write the client?

I’m currently using netbeans 6.9.1

Comment: Are you having the wsdl(url) ?

Comment: Yes I do have access to the WSDL, it's an RPC/encoded WSDL.

Comment: Just check the answer that I had given. I think it should work. HTH

Comment: on your solutions:

1) I’m using netbeans as states above and so far I don’t think there is any plug-ins to generate stubs for netbeans. However I also do use Eclipse the current version I’m using is Version: Helios Service Release 2, when I performed the steps of placing the plug in the plug-in or drop-in folders the wizard still does not show an axis option.

2) When I used the web-services plug-in it always states that it can’t find the wsdl or invalid wsdl when I pass URL

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5340/discussion-between-im-adan-and-ajj)

Comment: Try using axis-1.4 it worked for me. Follow the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22784062/error-parsing-wsdl-with-exception-use-encoded/23759285

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to generate the client stub from the wsdl url, then [follow this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020755/how-to-convert-wsdl-to-java/7020874#7020874)

Thank you

Comment: Yes After re-installing Eclipise I managed to get it working with the Web Services Wizard, it has generated the stubs using Axis 1.4 and now it is time to write the client, your help was very much appreciated. Thank you.