# Error parsing WSDL with exception use="encoded"

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, wsimport

Everytime I run **wsimport**, I get this error:

> [ERROR] "Use of SOAP Encoding is not supported. 
>   SOAP extension element on line 65 in file:dummy.wsdl has use="encoded" "
>           Failed to parse the WSDL.

WSDL (error block):

```
<wsdl:input name="dummyRequest">
        <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                   namespace="urn:cmg.stdapp.webservices.generalplugin" use="encoded" />
</wsdl:input>
```

Answer (score 29):

This is because the given WSDL is using 'encoded' which is a RPC encoding and a very old way of doing things.
RPC encoding is not supported by wsimport

[Some more info on your error message](https://github.com/javaee/metro-jax-ws/issues/930)

As an alternative try use [Apache Axis](http://axis.apache.org/axis/) which is yucky and old, but I guess it will get you going.

For a Maven project, drop your WSDL in src/main/resources/wsdl
And add the following to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
   <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
   <version>1.4</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
   <artifactId>axis-jaxrpc</artifactId>
   <version>1.4</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.2</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<plugins>
...
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
   <artifactId>axistools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.4</version>
   <executions>
       <execution>
           <goals>
               <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
           </goals>
       </execution>
   </executions>
   <configuration>
       <packageSpace>com.mycompany.service.client</packageSpace>
       <sourceDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdl</sourceDirectory>
       <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/wsdl2java</outputDirectory>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I needed a client for an rpc/encoded web service. These instructions "just worked". Thanks