# Generate client from http authenticated wsdl

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services

I'm trying to generate a web service client with the eclipse Web Service Client wizard. However, the wsdl needs http authentication, and haven't found a way to enter the authentication information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the wsdl in a browser and enter the login information when prompted. Once the wsdl opens save it to a file on your hard drive. Use the file with eclipse to generate your code. Then you may have to replace the endpoint value in the java code created because it will contain the location of the file instead of the deployed wsdl. I've had to do it this way a couple of times to get around the authentication piece.