# Spring boot app: The service definition selected is invalid

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, wsdl

I am developing one spring boot application for that I have one wsdl file. I want to generate client for it. But while I am trying to do it, it is giving error "The service definition selected is invalid". And when I am trying to browse it , it is not giving any option. Give me suggestion how to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this answer helps,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642587/web-service-client-service-definition-selected-is-invalid

Comment: I checked all the suggestions Everything is fine for my application.