# Creating client for web service

Tags: web-services, jboss

I have deployed a simple hello service in jboss server. I can view the wsdl file. Can someone help me with the client side. I mean how to access this service? Is there any way to access from web browser? Method deployed is

```
@WebMethod
public String greet( @WebParam(name = "name")
String name )
    {
   return "Hello" + name;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to know what is the wsdl url to access the service which you have just exposed. It might most probably be something like "http://localhost: < port-number >/ems-ejb/?wsdl"

If you type the same in the browser, you should be able to see the wsdl file (page with full of xml tags).

Once done, follow the steps [provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020755/how-to-convert-wsdl-to-java/7020874#7020874)

Example on how to call the method once client stub is generated

```
String endpoint = "your wsdl url";
GreetImplServiceLocator objGreetImplServiceLocator = new GreetImplServiceLocator();
java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(endpoint);
GreetIntf objGreetIntf = objGreetImplServiceLocator.getFaultImplPort(url);
 String greetings=objFaultIntf.greet("stackoverflow");
```

Comment: Thanks. I got the wsdl url. Even i got the stubs in eclipse. But i dont know what to do next? How do i get access to my service? When i try to add the client project to server (add or remove option) it forms an .ear file and deploy it on jboss. But that i am not able to access from browser. when i type  http://localhost:8080/filename in the url i get that the link is broken

Comment: From the client stub you just generated, you can see an interface having the method greet() You just need to call it. Refer the example which I added in the answer

Comment: ya thanks. Still facing hell lot of problems. But perhaps it is with my eclipse configuration. Thanks again