# After creating Java files from WSDL, how do I call the service?

Tags: java, wsdl

I am a beginner in web-services.

I created a jar out of the given WSDL file; Now how do I use the service? The doesn't seem to be an API there.

It looks like there are many tools that can be used to generate Java code from WSDL. Does using different tools mean different ways of calling the service ?

Answer (score 1):

[This will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654517/creating-client-for-web-service/8654927#8654927). It explains you how to call the web services which has been exposed.