# Axis2 Webservice Fault - The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, soap, apache-axis

Hi created a test application to learn Axis2. I packed the axis with my war and afetr deployment  the WSDL is also acessible via URL - `http://localhost:8081/SajuAxis2/test/service/SajuServices.wsdl`

But when I try to invoke the service using client stub with the above URL, it is not working.

```
SajuServicesStub stub = new SajuServicesStub("http://localhost:8081/SajuAxis2/test/service/SajuServices?wsdl");
```

But if I replace the endpoint URL with `http://localhost:9091/SajuAxis2/SajuService/SajuServices.SajuServicesHttpEndpoint`  it is working. I am using JDK1.6 and JBoss. I have included the axis2.xml in conf of metainf and also the **services.xml** as below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This file was auto-generated from WSDL -->
<!-- by the Apache Axis2 version: 1.5.6  Built on : Aug 30, 2011 (10:00:16 CEST) -->
<serviceGroup>
    <service name="SajuServices">
        <messageReceivers>
            <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-out" class="service.SajuServicesMessageReceiverInOut"/>
        </messageReceivers>
        <parameter name="ServiceClass">service.SajuServicesSkeleton</parameter>
        <parameter name="useOriginalwsdl">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="modifyUserWSDLPortAddress">true</parameter>
        <operation name="process" mep="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-out" namespace="http://service">
            <actionMapping>urn:process</actionMapping>
            <outputActionMapping>urn:processResponse</outputActionMapping>
            <faultActionMapping faultName="RemoteException">urn:processRemoteException</faultActionMapping>
        </operation>
    </service>
</serviceGroup>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654517/creating-client-for-web-service/8654927#8654927

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. It was a misconfiguration in axis2.xml. I given wrong context path.

```
<parameter name="servicePath">SimpleService</parameter>
```

udated to

```
<parameter name="servicePath">services</parameter>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to  provide service endpoint url..Not the wsdl url.
You are sending requests to the service to be processed..not to the wsdl.

Comment: But I have some other applications working with the WSDL URL.