# There is no endpoint listening when connecting to the service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I am trying to connect to a web service. I have a wsdl that I converted to class using SVCUTIL..

When calling the service from .net console application, I get this error

There was no endpoint listening at https://rest.developer.yodlee.com:8080/yodsoap/services/RoutingNumberServiceService_2017Q1 that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Inner exception : Unable to connect to remote server

I am not sure what I am doing here and how to fix this..

Below is the wsdl's service info..

```
<wsdl:service name="RoutingNumberServiceService">
    <wsdl:port binding="impl:RoutingNumberServiceSoapBinding" name="RoutingNumberService">
        <wsdlsoap:address location="http://localhost:8080/yodsoap/services/RoutingNumberService_2017Q1/" />
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

This is the client's config

```
<client>

  <endpoint address="https://rest.developer.yodlee.com:8080/yodsoap/services/RoutingNumberServiceService_2017Q1"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RoutingNumberServiceSoapBinding"
      contract="RoutingNumberServiceService.RoutingNumberService" name="RoutingNumberService"  />

</client>
```

Can someone help me understand what is that I am missing here.. Appreciate the help. I tried a lot of solutions online and nothing helped me. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Your links shows `https://rest.` but the xml you have posted shows `https://resr` which if either are correct.

Comment: @Scrobi - that was a typo. I corrected. Thanks

Comment: `https://rest.developer.yodlee.com` seem to respond even from here but `https://rest.developer.yodlee.com:8080` doesn't. Maybe the port 8080 isn't open on the other end ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is `Unable to connect to remote server`.

I tried telnetting to that server

```
$> telnet rest.developer.yodlee.com 8080
Connecting To rest.developer.yodlee.com...Could not open connection to the host, on port 8080: Connect failed
```

so it appears the endpoint is inaccessible - possibly it's been turned off or that is not the correct address.

One thing I note is that 8080 is an unusual port to be running a HTTPS service on - 443 and 8443 are the standard ports for HTTPS.

Regardless, the only way you can "fix" it is to contact the endpoint owner and ask them what the issue is.

***EDIT***

---

[The documentation](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_SOAP_API_Reference) states that the base URL is  https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/services/v1.0, which is (implicitly) port 443. I think the port number is your problem.

***EDIT 2***

---

What I am trying to suggest is that you fix the following line:

```
<endpoint address="https://rest.developer.yodlee.com:8080/yodsoap/services/RoutingNumberServiceService_2017Q1"
```

to be

```
<endpoint address="https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/yodsoap/services/RoutingNumberServiceService_2017Q1"
```

Note that I have removed `:8080`.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this.. But when I use https instead of http (without port number), it asks me to use http..

Comment: `asks me to use http`? What do you mean by this? Do you get an error message? If so, what exactly is it? Your configuration shows that you *are* using HTTPS so I am very confused by your statement. Please be precise in your answers - we do not have all the information you have :)

Comment: Actually - I think I understand you - see my **EDIT 2**. I think you misunderstood what I was suggesting :)

Comment: Thank you... But When I changed it like you said, the exception says "The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference (EPR) https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/yodsoap/services/RoutingNumberServiceService_2017Q1..

At least something different. Does this mean something good?!

Comment: Yes - that is better because it means you are actually connecting to the service. Please see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16192151/axis2-webservice-fault-the-service-cannot-be-found-for-the-endpoint-reference) which is related to your new error.

Comment: I think it makes sense now. I will work on fixing the issues that I am getting as a response. At least I am getting a response. Thank you! Appreciate the time!!