# steps for creating jax-ws webservice using myeclipse

Tags: java, android

I am new to websevices in java. Can any one please tell me the step by step procedure for how to create jax-ws webservice using myeclipse. Please share me if any good material you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnayl.html) to create the functionalities which you'd like to expose, using JAX-WS.

Once the wsdl is generated, you can follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020755/how-to-convert-wsdl-to-java/7020874#7020874) to know how to call the methods exposed by you, form a different system.