# Webservices :Understanding the task assigned

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I am a complete newbie to web services and I am working alone. My lead mailed me a task to complete. I think he has hard coded the information and he wants me to replace the hard coded data from web services.

He has mailed me a WSDL file and said

> Make the jar file from the wsdl.

What does this mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tools which will generate Java code to talk to web services, performing serialization and deserialization effectively, so that your client code can talk in terms of Java objects rather than raw SOAP.

You should find out which of these tools is being used in your project, and apply it to the WSDL provided.

(Also, it's a good idea to get used to asking for more information when you don't understand the assignment. A good team leader - or anyone, really - should be more than happy to help you.)

Answer (score 0):

Generate the Java stubs from the wsdl.
[wsdl2Java](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/userguide-creatingclients.html)

[wsdl2Java](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/userguide-creatingclients-xmlbeans.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with eclipse, then the task can be completed easily. I think he is asking for the jar of client stub which can be produced from the wsdl.

**In that case do:** In eclipse, make sure you have webservices plugin. [Follow this after that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020755/how-to-convert-wsdl-to-java/7020874#7020874)

You will have few .java files being exported. Try to compile them and generate the .class files. Now jar the .class files using command in command prompt

```
jar -cvf <Name of the jar>.jar *
```